# print users that have specific roles in a list Flutter Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to return a list for every different role,
I have three roles and I used a toggle bar to toggle between different lists for the different roles.
how do I get the list of users who have that specific role?

I am a beginner in flutter

I am new to firebase as well as flutter so I was just messing around trying to figure it out on my own, and I don't know whether I am on the right track or not I checked different places but I did not get anything.

here is the document fields in my firestore database: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kqxg.jpg

Comment: You should start by reading through the documentation to learn how it works and see some examples.  https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/